# Can't update ggplot2 to the newest version

Tags: r, ggplot2, package

I've run out of ideas how to update my ggplot2 package to the newest version (v.3.0.0). I've already updated my R version and tried to update this one package several times:

1. I checked for package updates with tools in RStudio, but I got a message that everything is up to date, even though my ggplot2's version is still 2.1.0
2. I tried to remove and reinstall this package, but it didn't work either. Still the same version.
3. I tried with update.packages (with argument "ask = FALSE") but I got a prompt if I'd like to use a personal library. I don't, so I can't update it this way too.
4. I tried to install a collection of packages "tidyverse", thinking maybe this would help, but no, it didn't.

How can I update this one particular package 'ggplot2'?

Comment: What version of R are you running?

Comment: It's R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02) "Feather Spray"

Comment: How about installing from GitHub? `install.packages("devtools");
devtools::install_github("tidyverse/ggplot2")`. You will need to install RTools first

Comment: If you got any error, make sure to post everything showed in the terminal so others can help

Comment: Ok, so I don't know how it happened, but yesterday I noticed that my ggplot2 version updated to 3.0.0 even though I haven't done anything more than what I listed above, so something must have worked, just not instantly.
Anyway, thank you for your help.